# Un Ordered execution of the instructions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am calling Details function it is giving empty details because Details function is executing before getting the data from the json file. How to resolve the problem?

```
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,login){
 $scope.user=login.Details();
}

app.factory('login',function($cookieStore,$http){
 var users=[];
 $http.get("js/user.json").success(function(data){
    angular.copy(data,users);
 });
return{
 Details:function()
    {
        alert(users);
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `$scope.user` in the success callback of your `$http.get`.  The best way to do that is to define the success function in your controller and pass it into your service.  So your service becomes:

```
app.factory('login', function($cookieStore,$http){
    var userCache;

    return {
        doLogin: function(user, password, successCallback) {
            if(!userCache) {
                $http.get("js/user.json").success(function(data) {
                    userCache = data;
                    successCallback(data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your controller gets this added somewhere in a click handler or something:

```
login.doLogin('sampleUsername', 'samplePassword', function(data) {
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

That should do most of what you need, you might need to adjust depending on how you're validating logins and what that sample JSON file contains.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Of cousre it wil give You empty user , because you've defined your var user=[];
and then and Ajax call , and then you are returning that user , So because you're not doing this asynchronously , all of them will fire synchronous and Javascript will be pleased to return an emtpy user :!!!

There are some ways to solve this , using promise is one of them

```
   app.factory('login',function(){
     return{
       Details:function(){
         promise = $http.get("js/user.json");
         promise.then(function(data){
           return data;
      });
    }

   }
         });
```

OR you can Simply do this :

```
 app.factory('login',function(){
     return{
         Details:function(){
             $http.get("js/user.json")
                 .success(function(data){
                     return data;
                 })
                       }
                }

          });
```